# Thymeleaf th:field in textarea not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have a description in several languages, using thymeleaf I came across the fact that th:field in textarea not working!

At the same time th:text or th:value in input works and updates the data on POST request.

**Please help me find the cause**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWrMO.png)

```
<label>Description</label>
<textarea id="description" th:field="*{description}" placeholder="Enter content">
</textarea>

//This works, but I need to use "textarea"
<input type="text" th:value="${description}" th:name="description"/>

//Controller
@GetMapping("/{language}/post/{id}/edit")
    public String editPost(@PathVariable Language language,
                                   @PathVariable Long id,
                                   Model model) throws Exception {

        model.addAttribute("post", postService.getPost(id));
        model.addAttribute("language", language.getCode());

        String description = postService.getDescription(id, language);
        model.addAttribute("description", description);
        return "admin/post-edit";
    }
```

Tried different options - nothing helps (((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `th:text` to set the content of the `<textarea>`:

```
<textarea id="description" th:name="description" th:text="${description}" 
          placeholder="Enter content"></textarea>
```